# SQL pivot the column values

Tags: mysql, sql

### [Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen):

Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. **The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.**

Note: Print NULL when there are no more names corresponding to an occupation.

Occupation will only contain one of the following values: Doctor, Professor, Singer or Actor.

**Sample Input**

[image]

**Sample Output**

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

---

My solution:

```
select Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor from
(
    select a.name, a.occupation, count(*) as row_num from Occupations a
    join Occupations b 
    on a.occupation=b.occupation and (a.name>=b.name)
    group by a.name, a.occupation
    order by row_num asc;
) as t
PIVOT
(
    max(name)
    for occupation in (Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor)
)
as pvt;
```

**Error:**

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

**Line no 7:**

```
order by row_num asc;
```

I am trying to learn Advanced sql concepts so as far as now I am able to write the query but I am getting this error. When I run the subquery it works fine and I get some output but after using pivot I get this error. I don't know how to solve it and what's causing this error.

I want to do it by `pivot` operator and without using `row_number`.

**Subquery:**

```
select a.name, a.occupation, count(*) as row_num from Occupations a
.
.
order by row_num;
```

**Subquery output:**

```
Belvet Professor 1
Jane Singer 1
Jennifer Actor 1
Julia Doctor 1
Britney Professor 2
Priya Doctor 2
Ketty Actor 2
Jenny Singer 2
Maria Professor 3
Samantha Actor 3
Kristeen Singer 3
Meera Professor 4
Naomi Professor 5
Priyanka Professor 6
```

Comment: I am trying to do it via pivot and making own row_number function. I can't seem to make it to work.

Comment: `PIVOT` is a proprietary feature of Microsoft SQL Server. As in, they invented it, and it's not a standard feature of the SQL language. All vendors add their own enhancements to SQL. They don't all support the same enhancements.

Comment: Oh. I was following the tutorial https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/. Did not see-> it was not a part of mysql. So there is no operator named pivot it's just an enhancement. Basic and general method of doing is via using subqueries and group by function. Thanks @BillKarwin for clarifying these things. I was scratching my head on this for so long. The answer got accepted in ms sql server editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    rn,
    max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) doctor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) singer,
    max(case when occupation = 'Actor'  then name end) actor
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) rn
    from mytable t
)
group by rn
```

The subquery ranks persons having the same occupatin by name. You can then use that information to generate the rows, and access the corresponding name for each occupation with a conditional aggregate.

Without window functions, it is different. If your data is not too large, one option emulates row number with a subquery:

```
select
    rn,
    max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) doctor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) singer,
    max(case when occupation = 'Actor'  then name end) actor
from (
    select t.*, 
        (
            select count(*) 
            from mytable t1 
            where t1.occupation = t.occupation and t1.name <= t.name
        ) rn
    from mytable t
)
group by rn
```

Comment: can't use `row_number()` function :(. not allowed in their version of mysql.

Comment: I am trying to learn it via pivot and this max/min thing.  But will try to learn it via other methods also. I can't seem to find why this error occurs.

Comment: Well, as a starter: you query is missing keyword `from` before the first opening parenthese.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am looking for solution using `pivot` and without using `row_number` function.  I am stuck at creating solution using this only. But thanks for providing the alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

This query uses a subquery to create temporary columns for each occupation (Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor) and assigns names to these columns based on the occupation. The ROW_NUMBER() function is used to assign a unique row number to each name within its occupation group, ordered alphabetically.

The outer query then groups the results by the row number and selects the maximum value for each occupation. The MAX function is used to get the alphabetically ordered list of names for each occupation. If there is no name for a specific occupation in a row, the result will be NULL.

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(Doctor) AS Doctor,
    MAX(Professor) AS Professor,
    MAX(Singer) AS Singer,
    MAX(Actor) AS Actor
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END AS Doctor,
        CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name END AS Professor,
        CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name END AS Singer,
        CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name END AS Actor,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS rn
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
) AS temp
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```