# How Do Efficiently I Convert Dynamic Rows to Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert rows to columns in the SQL server, I heard that PIVOT is not very fast, and I need to deal with a lot of records.

I tried following on this [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server) but still not solved with my below example

This is my example: (updated)

```
   -----------------------------------------------
   | Id | Value  | ColumnName    | Submission_Id |
   -----------------------------------------------
   | 1  | John   | FirstName     | 1             |
   | 2  | 2.4    | Amount        | 1             |
   | 3  | ZH1E4A | PostalCode    | 1             |
   | 4  | Fork   | LastName      | 1             |
   | 5  | 857685 | AccountNumber | 1             |
   | 6  | Donny  | FirstName     | 2             |
   | 7  | 2.7    | Amount        | 2             |
   | 8  | ZH1E4C | PostalCode    | 2             |
   | 9  | Yen    | LastName      | 2             |
   | 10 | 857686 | AccountNumber | 2             |
   -----------------------------------------------
```

This is my expected result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| FirstName  |Amount|   PostalCode   |   LastName  |  AccountNumber |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| John       | 2.4  |   ZH1E4A       |   Fork      |  857685        |
| Donny      | 2.7  |   ZH1E4C       |   Yen       |  857686        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I build the result?

Comment: How exactly the question you mentioned fails to be of help?

Comment: How do you relate `LastName` = `Fork` is associated with `FirstName` = `John` and not with `FirstName` = `Donny ` ? and further you say `SQL server` in question but tagged `mysql`

Comment: Your question has `mysql` tag and `PIVOT` operator is defined in `MS SQL`. mentioned pivot function has nothing to do with mysql

Comment: Does MySQL even have any such functionality, slow or fast? Can you do it in the presentation layer instead?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @Nae I'm failed when using an aggregate function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL pivot the column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068684/sql-pivot-the-column-values)

Comment: @Nae The table already has submission_id so for `Jhon` has submission_id=1 and for `Donny` has 2 and so on

Comment: The answer mentioned in the above question(posted by me) will be same in your case.

Comment: @Pygirl I'll try it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group them by their associative key, [which you informed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238449/how-do-efficiently-i-convert-dynamic-rows-to-column-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment113596221_64238449):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'FirstName'     THEN Value END) AS FirstName,
  MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'Amount'        THEN Value END) AS Amount,
  MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'PostalCode'    THEN Value END) AS PostalCode,
  MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'LastName'      THEN Value END) AS LastName,
  MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'AccountNumber' THEN Value END) AS AccountNumber
FROM table
GROUP BY submission_id
;
```

`GROUP BY` enforces that there is single row for each unique `submission_id`, `MAX` selects the most descendant value of the expression for that particular group key (it is assumed to be singular so aggregate type should not matter), and finally `CASE` is filtering the `Value` by `ColumnName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
indata(Id,Value,ColumnName) AS (
          SELECT 1,'John'   ,'FirstName'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'2.4'    ,'Amount'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'ZH1E4A' ,'PostalCode'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Fork'   ,'LastName'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'857685' ,'AccountNumber'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'Donny'  ,'FirstName'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'2.7'    ,'Amount'
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'ZH1E4C' ,'PostalCode'
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'Yen'    ,'LastName'
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'857686','AccountNumber'
)
,
-- need to get a grouping column, one that 
-- changes every time we encounter a 'FirstName
-- add a counter that is at 1 for FirstName
-- otherwise at 0, and build a running sum...
w_session_id AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'FirstName' THEN 1 END) 
    OVER(ORDER BY id) AS sessid
  , *
  FROM indata
)
-- now un-pivot manually 
SELECT
  sessid                                                   AS id
, MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'FirstName'     THEN value END) AS FirstName
, MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'Amount'        THEN value END) AS Amount
, MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'PostalCode'    THEN value END) AS PostalCode
, MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'LastName'      THEN value END) AS LastName
, MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'AccountNumber' THEN value END) AS AccountNumber
FROM w_session_id
GROUP BY sessid;
-- out  id | FirstName | Amount | PostalCode | LastName | AccountNumber 
-- out ----+-----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------
-- out   1 | John      | 2.4    | ZH1E4A     | Fork     | 857685
-- out   2 | Donny     | 2.7    | ZH1E4C     | Yen      | 857686
```